# Fetching browser language not working

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-browser

I have a piece of JS code in my webpage that fetches me the browser's language. The code is very simple:

```
function browserLanguage() {
        return navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    }
```

But its failing in cases when the users are using Chrome browser in the Android phones. I am capturing user agents too. And I see that its been failing for mobiles and tabs. These are the user agents for which the above code was failing

- Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46
  (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13G36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-T813 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98
  Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
  Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36

And many more.

Can some one please tell what is the best way to capture the language? Solution to this problem as well as pointers would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: failing on chrome or mozilla ?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 are there for almost all the browsers. You can ignore that.